# Are there any differences between autolayout when it was released in iOS 6 vs in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Are there any differences between autolayout when it was released in iOS 6 vs the version released with iOS 7?

Comment: See [this article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/auto-layout-updates-in-ios-7/)

Comment: The article is not complete.  For example, it doesn't mention NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint.